# The Nash equilibrium, an existence proof

Tags: inequality, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I do not follow [here](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs295-8/nash.pdf) in the -4th line
that the equality is achieved only if

$$p_i(s,\alpha)\leq 0$$

for every $s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p_i(s,\alpha)\leq 0$ for every $s$, then $\alpha'_{i} = \alpha_{i}$, thus we get equality (proving "if" but not "only if").

Suppose there exists an $\hat{s}$ where $p_i(\hat{s},\alpha)> 0$, then for any $s$ where $p_i(s,\alpha)\leq 0$ and $\alpha_{i}^{(s)} > 0$ we have $\alpha_{i}^{\prime(s)} < \alpha_{i}^{(s)}$, which implies:
$$\sum_{s:p_{i}(s, \alpha)\leq0} \alpha_{i}^{\prime(s)} < \sum_{s:p_{i}(s, \alpha)\leq0} \alpha_{i}^{(s)}$$
(Note, there must exist such an $s$ because $\alpha_{i}$ cannot result in strictly lower payoff than all pure strategies in its support.)
$$\Rightarrow \sum_{s:p_{i}(s, \alpha)>0} \alpha_{i}^{\prime(s)} > \sum_{s:p_{i}(s, \alpha)>0} \alpha_{i}^{(s)}$$
The last implication follows because $\sum\limits_{s}\alpha_{i}^{\prime(s)}=\sum\limits_{s}\alpha_{i}^{(s)}=1$.

Hence, we can say equality is achieved if and only if $p_i(s,\alpha)\leq 0$ for every $s$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What does this number mean: $$\alpha_{i}^{'(s)} $$ ?

Comment: @user3357120 I've always had this typographical issue with my apostrophes, but I've just learned [how to fix it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96558/my-prime-symbol-is-not-superscript), I presume it is clear now?

Comment: I still haven't understood why "Hence, we can say equality is achieved if and only if $p_i(s,\alpha)\leq 0$ for every $s$." ... Could you please elaborate a little bit more ?

Comment: @user3357120 We've shown that the expression holds with equality if $p_i(s,\alpha)\leq 0$ for all $s$.  We have also shown the expression does not hold with equality if $p_i(s,\alpha)\leq 0$ does not hold, i.e. if there exists an $\hat{s}$ where $p_i(\hat{s},\alpha)> 0$.  Therefore, the expression:
$$\sum_{s:p_{i}(s, \alpha)>0} \alpha_{i}^{\prime(s)} \geq \sum_{s:p_{i}(s, \alpha)>0} \alpha_{i}^{(s)}$$
holds with equality if and only if $p_i(s,\alpha)\leq 0$ for all $s$.

Comment: But you state there in your answer that there is such an $s$ and **not** $\hat{s}$  : "Note, there must exist such an $s$ because $\alpha_i$ cannot result in strictly lower payoff than all pure strategies in its support." But in your last comment you say: "if there exists an $\hat{s}$"

Comment: @user3357120 I'm assuming there exists such an $\hat{s}$ where $p_i(\hat{s},\alpha)> 0$.  Then, by the definition of $\alpha'$, for any $s$ where $p_i(s,\alpha)\leq 0$ and $\alpha_{i}^{(s)} > 0$ we have $\alpha_{i}^{\prime(s)} < \alpha_{i}^{(s)}$. I want to conclude:
$$\sum_{s:p_{i}(s, \alpha)\leq0} \alpha_{i}^{\prime(s)} < \sum_{s:p_{i}(s, \alpha)\leq0} \alpha_{i}^{(s)}$$
However, I cannot conclude this if the set $\{s:p_{i}(s, \alpha)\leq0\}$ is empty since the summations would then each be zero.  Thus, I need to argue there exists such an $s$ as in the note.

Comment: I use the existence of an $\hat{s}$ where $p_i(\hat{s},\alpha)> 0$ in conjunction with the definition of $\alpha_{i}'$ to get that $\alpha_{i}^{\prime(s)} < \alpha_{i}^{(s)}$ for any $s$ where $p_i(s,\alpha)\leq 0$ and $\alpha_{i}^{(s)} > 0$.  The assumption that there exists such an $\hat{s}$ is critical to the argument that we then get a strict inequality.

Comment: I didn't imagine that my simple question is so involved when I asked it.

Comment: @user3357120 Haha, it is definitely not mathematically immediate, which is why it's a good question. The author probably found it intuitive (the summations are equal only if $\alpha$ doesn't change) and left it at that.

Comment: How would you proof in one English sentence that for some $s$ in the support of $\alpha_i$ we do not do strictly better than in $\alpha_i$ ? It is intuitive but an exact argument would be nice .

Comment: The expected utility from the mixed strategy $\alpha_{i}$ is a convex combination of the utility from each pure strategy in its support.  Therefore, the expected utility from $\alpha_{i}$ cannot be below the utility from every pure strategy in its support.